# Posistioning .card-img-top on bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design something very similar to the image shown below using bootstrap [image]

I'm having issues with aligning the `.card-img-top` images vertically with the space between them. I tried putting both '.card-img-top' images in the same '.col' then applying padding which didn't produce the result I wanted.

I have provided my code [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/webi108/dmerj8t5/1/)

Comment: Which element are you having trouble with? The third column on the right?

Comment: Code relevant to your question belongs directly into your question, not just dumped on an external site - please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @MathiasRechtigel Yes the third column

Answer (score 1):

Try nesting a bootstrap row within the last column then put some padding between like so:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card img-fluid">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.treeservicesmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/safety-ppe-image.jpg" alt="Card image">
              <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <p class="card-text">Personal <br>Protective Equipment.</p>
                <a href="#">SHOP NOW</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12" style="padding-top:20px;">
            <div class="card img-fluid">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.treeservicesmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/safety-ppe-image.jpg" alt="Card image">
              <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <p class="card-text">Personal <br>Protective Equipment.</p>
                <a href="#">SHOP NOW</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The third column just overlaps the rest of the cards, when the screen is resized